# How do I unambiguously define a single-statement switch branch in Bison?

Tags: bison

The desire is to define a [switch statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) in which the definition of a branch is surrounded by curly braces, but the braces may be omitted for single-statement branches, like a single-statement `if` block.

An example of the desired syntax (white-spaced for clarity):

```
switch
   condition1
      blah
   | condition2 {
      blah
      blah
   }
   | condition3
   | condition4
      switch
         nested_condition
            blah
```

I have the following grammar, but it has a shift/reduce conflict:

```
%token <union_string> T_ID   "identifier"

%% // begin rules

program:
    statement_list
    ;

statement_list:
    statement_list statement
    | empty
    ;

statement:
    T_ID //added for completeness
    | "switch" switch_branch_list //the subject of the switch is elided for brevity
    ;

switch_branch_list:
    switch_branch_list "|" switch_branch
    | switch_branch
    ;

switch_branch:
    T_ID statement
    | T_ID "{" statement_list "}"
    ;

empty:
    ;
```

The conflict:

```
...
State 9

    5 statement: "switch" switch_branch_list .
    6 switch_branch_list: switch_branch_list . "|" switch_branch

    "|"  shift, and go to state 13

    "|"       [reduce using rule 5 (statement)]
    $default  reduce using rule 5 (statement)
...
```

How might one resolve the shift/reduce conflict in the given grammar?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing terminates your switch statement, so if the target of a switch branch is another switch statement, the program becomes ambiguous.

I'd recommend not allowing a switch (or other compound statement) to be the direct target of a branch. Insist that it be surrounded with braces.

So you would end up with something like this:

```
statement:          simple_statement | compound_statement
simple_statement:   expr
                    | '{' statement_list '}'
                    | ...
compound_statement: switch_statement
                    | ...
statement_list      /* empty */ | statement_list statement  

switch_statement:   "switch" expr branch_list
branch_list:        branch | branch_list '|' branch
branch:             T_ID simple_statement
```

Note that I put the block statement syntax (`'{' statement_list '}'`) as one of the productions for `simple_statement`. Normally, that is what it is, much as a parenthesized expression is a production for `term` in a standard expression grammar. But it's all just a suggestion.